# Anti Virus Service does not run - Windows XP SP3 32bit Home

Tags: windows-xp, anti-virus, services

I have a somewhat strange problem here.

I am trying to run Anti Virus Software on my Windows XP Home 32bit System.
After a serious crash I had to fall back to an outdated copy of my initial installation and had Windows install 5 years of updates. So far so good.

After Intalling a new Anti Virus Software (Bitdefender 2012) everything seemed to be fine, initial scanning went fine and configuration was working.

But after restarting the System the Virus Scanner was unable to start up again. Even the Configuration console of the AV Software did not start.

I tried scanning the System for malware, but nothing was found.

Then I tried a different AV Software (MS Security Essentials), but in the end it did fail to start too.

I have tried to start the Service manually, but I seem to be missing the privilege to do so.

I am logged in as a Non-"Administrator" User with Admin privileges (Not much choices there on a XP Home System). I cannot switch to Administrator account outside the protected mode.
When running Windows in protected mode I am unable to start the AV Software because it does not run in protected mode.

I am a bit at loss now...

Comment: See my post, it could be a persistent mbr infection loading long before windows does...http://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now/157533#157533